# Python Recursion with ascii

Tags: python, recursion

I'm trying to create a function that takes a letter in and returns the the letter in the alphabet and all previous letters for example if the parameter was "c" it would return  c then b then a, this is what I tried with ascii but I'm stuck at this

```
def backwards_alphabet(n):
  if ord(n) == 97:
    return n
  else:
    return n + backwards_alphabet(ord(n-1))
```

Comment: You're `ord`-ing the input to the recursive call; your function looks like it expects a character, but passing `ord` results means you're recursively passing `int`. In any event, you need to provide [MCVE]s, not just "I'm stuck".

Answer (score 2):

You need to be careful when you call `ord`. It expects a `string` you're passing it an `int`. Simply convert the decremented ascii value to a string again before passing it to the function: `backwards_alphabet(chr(ord(n)-1))`.

Full code:

```
def backwards_alphabet(n):
  if ord(n) == 97:
    return n
  else:
    return n + backwards_alphabet(chr(ord(n)-1))

res = backwards_alphabet('c')

print(res)
```

Outputs `cba`

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursion with a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators):

```
def backwards_alphabet(n):
   if ord(n) == 97:
      yield "a"
   else:
      yield n
      for i in backwards_alphabet(chr(ord(n)-1)):
          for b in i:
              yield i

print(list(backwards_alphabet("f")))
```

Output:

```
['f', 'e', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'a']
```

Comment: Probably the downvote was from someone who could not understand all this stuff...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, my problem was with the `ord` I solved my problem, I was looking to do it like this:

```
def backwards_alphabet(letter):
  if ord(letter) == 97:
    return letter
  else:
    print(letter)
    return backwards_alphabet(chr(ord(letter)-1))

print(backwards_alphabet('c'))
```

Comment: Your proposed solution doesn't do what you said it needed to, "returns the letter in the alphabet and all previous letters" .It only ***returns*** one letter, `"a"`, and prints the rest as a side effect.  If you want a proper recursive function that returns the backwards alphabet, see @Anonta's answer (+1)